# Experimental design and choosing a statistical test

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, experiment-design

I'm doing my thesis project and one component of it is to look at how ingesting plastics might influence oxygen consumption in marine snails.

So I have an independent categorical variable (food treatment - A, B, C... where A is algae, B is algae+plastics, C is plastics) and have 10 snails exposed to each. I have another independent variable of time. The oxygen consumption for each snail was measured post-exposure at time intervals of every 5 minutes. So, that makes oxygen consumption my dependent variable (where it has been measured repeatedly for each snail used). I want to test the significance of plastic exposure to the rate of oxygen consumption, and particularly if having plastic through the algae is significant.

I'm not a statistician, but I'm fairly familiar with R. I'm just not entirely sure what test I should be using. I've come up with a repeated measures one-way ANOVA or a randomized block ANOVA. Does this sound like it would work? I'm not even sure if what I'm wanting is possible.